# signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000000 comes in my app

Tags: android

when i run my app it runs properly but after sometime my app closes and control comes on home screen. and logcat produces statements as below..

```
INFO/DEBUG(27): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:1.6/Donut/20842:eng/test-keys'
INFO/DEBUG(27): pid: 818, tid: 829  >>> com.nga.dating.Activities <<<

INFO/DEBUG(27): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000000

INFO/DEBUG(27):  r0 00000007  r1 411b9a50  r2 411b9a50  r3 00000000
INFO/DEBUG(27):  r4 411b9a50  r5 001b1660  r6 00000000  r7 45dd5cac
INFO/DEBUG(27):  r8 45dd5da0  r9 4257de48  10 4257de34  fp 00000001
INFO/DEBUG(27):  ip ad083e5c  sp 45dd5c48  lr ad047361  pc ad03fc86  cpsr 00000030
INFO/DEBUG(27):          #00  pc 0003fc86  /system/lib/libdvm.so

INFO/DEBUG(27):          #01  pc 0002f480  /system/lib/libdvm.so 
INFO/DEBUG(27):          #02  pc 001f3c3a  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
INFO/DEBUG(27):          #03  pc 00260b52  /system/lib/libwebcore.so

INFO/DEBUG(27):          #04  pc 000dac68  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
INFO/DEBUG(27):          #05  pc 000ecc5c  /system/lib/libwebcore.so

INFO/DEBUG(27):          #06  pc 000df8f4  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
INFO/DEBUG(27):          #07  pc 00188638  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
INFO/DEBUG(27):          #08  pc 001887b4  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
INFO/DEBUG(27):          #09  pc 001887e0  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
INFO/DEBUG(27):          #10  pc 00258aa6  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
INFO/DEBUG(27):          #11  pc 0000e434  /system/lib/libdvm.so

INFO/DEBUG(27):          #12  pc 00040b0e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(27):          #13  pc 00013198  /system/lib/libdvm.so

INFO/DEBUG(27):          #14  pc 00017be4  /system/lib/libdvm.so

INFO/DEBUG(27):          #15  pc 0001762c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(27):          #16  pc 0005282c  /system/lib/libdvm.so

INFO/DEBUG(27):          #17  pc 0005284a  /system/lib/libdvm.so

INFO/DEBUG(27):          #18  pc 00047800  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(27):          #19  pc 0000f940  /system/lib/libc.so

INFO/DEBUG(27):          #20  pc 0000f4b4  /system/lib/libc.so

INFO/DEBUG(27): stack:
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c08  45dd5c40  
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c0c  001b1660  [heap]
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c10  4182712a  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex
 INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c14  4182712b  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c18  001b1660  [heap]
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c1c  00000001  
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c20  00000007  
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c24  4106ffe0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c28  001b1660  [heap]
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c2c  00000001  
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c30  00000007  
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c34  ad047361  /system/lib/libdvm.so

INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c38  411b9a50  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c3c  001b1660  [heap]
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c40  df002777  
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c44  e3a070ad  
INFO/DEBUG(27): #00 45dd5c48  00378450  [heap]
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c4c  ad06c89c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c50  ad03ff19  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c54  ad06c610  /system/lib/libdvm.so

INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c58  43825c80  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c5c  ad06c610  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c60  ad03fc71  /system/lib/libdvm.so

INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c64  001b10b8  [heap]

INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c68  00000000  
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c6c  ad02f483  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(27): #01 45dd5c70  ad06c610  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c74  ad02ff11  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c78  45dd5cac  
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c7c  411b9a50  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c80  aa3dc5d0  /system/lib/libwebcore.so

INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c84  ad02f409  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c88  aa1f3c25  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c8c  001b10b8  [heap]
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c90  00000000  
INFO/DEBUG(27):     45dd5c94  aa1f3c3d  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
DEBUG/Zygote(29): Process 818 terminated by signal (11)
INFO/ActivityManager(53): Process com.nga.dating.Activities (pid 818) has died.
INFO/WindowManager(53): WIN DEATH: Window{43880100 com.nga.dating.Activities/com.nga.dating.Activities.OptionActivity paused=false}
WARN/UsageStats(53): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.nga.dating.Activities

WARN/InputManagerService(53): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 818 uid 10022
```

how can i resolve this problem..
thanks in adv..

Comment: Are you using the NDK in your dating app :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of crash represents a bug in the firmware.

Try your code on hardware or an emulator running an unmodded recent Android ROM (e.g., Android 2.1 or newer). If the problem persists, create a project that can reproduce the crash, and post it, your crash log, and instructions on how to reproduce the problem at http://b.android.com.

If you are running on a modded ROM, the people developing the modded ROM may have their own bug report mechanism.

If you are simply running on older hardware (this appears to be Android 1.6), it may be that the bug has been fixed in newer versions of Android.

Comment: i am running in emulator 1.6 and 2.0 then this problem comes but when i run it on 2.1 or greater version it works fine.

Comment: actually i have only 2.1 and 2.2 device so i can't check it lower version device . so on device 1.6 and 2.0 it will work or not?

Comment: @hari: Sometimes the emulator has bugs that are not present in devices. There are no 2.0 devices -- they should all be on 2.1 now. So, try to find somebody with a 1.6 device you can borrow for five minutes... :-)