# Need help debugging further into a SEGV issue - Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, segmentation-fault

I am building a library with a large body of source code for Android.  The library works fine if compiled for Linux x86.  I am building it with the stand alone tool chain.  I have had success with this previously with other libraries, so I feel like my setup is good.  Anyway, compiling and linking are all good, but when I load the resultant shared library I get a SEGV.  This is the trace that I get:

```
03-23 23:37:14.213: I/DEBUG(28): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-23 23:37:14.213: I/DEBUG(28): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:2.1-update1/ECLAIR/35983:eng/test-keys'
03-23 23:37:14.224: I/DEBUG(28): pid: 332, tid: 332  >>> com.example.hellojni <<<
03-23 23:37:14.224: I/DEBUG(28): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000000
03-23 23:37:14.224: I/DEBUG(28):  r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 80808080  r3 00000000
03-23 23:37:14.224: I/DEBUG(28):  r4 00000000  r5 bea8154c  r6 bea81600  r7 00000000
03-23 23:37:14.224: I/DEBUG(28):  r8 bea81820  r9 41971894  10 00000354  fp bea814fc
03-23 23:37:14.224: I/DEBUG(28):  ip 80a81058  sp bea814c0  lr 80a63cd8  pc afe0e7c8  cpsr 40000010
03-23 23:37:14.313: I/DEBUG(28):          #00  pc 0000e7c8  /system/lib/libc.so
03-23 23:37:14.313: I/DEBUG(28):          #01  pc 00063cd4  /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/libgnustl_shared.so
03-23 23:37:14.323: I/DEBUG(28): code around pc:
03-23 23:37:14.323: I/DEBUG(28): afe0e7b8 e31c0003 1afffff6 e1a00002 e59f20d8 
03-23 23:37:14.323: I/DEBUG(28): afe0e7c8 e490c004 e0433000 f5d0f040 e04c13a2 
03-23 23:37:14.323: I/DEBUG(28): afe0e7d8 e0011002 e1d1100c 0490c004 1a000022 
03-23 23:37:14.323: I/DEBUG(28): code around lr:
03-23 23:37:14.323: I/DEBUG(28): 80a63cc8 e1a05000 e1a00001 e1a04001 ebff27d0 
03-23 23:37:14.323: I/DEBUG(28): 80a63cd8 e1a01004 e1a02000 e1a00005 e8bd4070 
03-23 23:37:14.323: I/DEBUG(28): 80a63ce8 eaffffa0 e590c000 e92d45f0 e51ce00c 
03-23 23:37:14.323: I/DEBUG(28): stack:
03-23 23:37:14.323: I/DEBUG(28):     bea81480  001479d0  [heap]
03-23 23:37:14.323: I/DEBUG(28):     bea81484  bea81820  [stack]
03-23 23:37:14.323: I/DEBUG(28):     bea81488  41971894  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
03-23 23:37:14.323: I/DEBUG(28):     bea8148c  00000354  
03-23 23:37:14.334: I/DEBUG(28):     bea81490  bea814fc  [stack]
03-23 23:37:14.334: I/DEBUG(28):     bea81494  00147a24  [heap]
03-23 23:37:14.334: I/DEBUG(28):     bea81498  00000006  
03-23 23:37:14.334: I/DEBUG(28):     bea8149c  80a63b58  /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/libgnustl_shared.so
03-23 23:37:14.334: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814a0  00000006  
03-23 23:37:14.334: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814a4  bea81548  [stack]
03-23 23:37:14.334: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814a8  80a82110  
03-23 23:37:14.334: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814ac  00000000  
03-23 23:37:14.334: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814b0  bea81820  [stack]
03-23 23:37:14.334: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814b4  80a63bcc  /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/libgnustl_shared.so
03-23 23:37:14.334: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814b8  df002777  
03-23 23:37:14.334: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814bc  e3a070ad  
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28): #00 bea814c0  bea814d4  [stack]
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814c4  00000000  
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28): #01 bea814c8  bea81548  [stack]
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814cc  bea81548  [stack]
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814d0  bea81600  [stack]
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814d4  8131f228  /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/libsharedB.so
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814d8  afe39190  /system/lib/libc.so
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814dc  bea8152c  [stack]
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814e0  001479a0  [heap]
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814e4  bea81548  [stack]
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814e8  80a8211c  
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814ec  001479a0  [heap]
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814f0  bea81548  [stack]
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814f4  bea81548  [stack]
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814f8  bea8151c  [stack]
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814fc  8131eb8c  /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/libsharedB.so
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea81500  bea8152c  [stack]
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea81504  0000272e  
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea81508  80a82124  
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea8150c  80a8211c  
03-23 23:37:14.884: D/Zygote(30): Process 332 terminated by signal (11)
03-23 23:37:14.893: I/ActivityManager(52): Process com.example.hellojni (pid 332) has died.
03-23 23:37:14.966: I/UsageStats(52): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.example.hellojni
```

If I use addr2line I get this info:

```
android-linux-addr2line.exe -C -f -e libc.so 0000e7c8
strlen
??:0

android-linux-addr2line.exe -C -f -e libgnustl_shared.so 00063cd4
std::string::operator=(char const*)
??:0
```

Ok, so there might be something going wrong with a static assignment of a string.  That would explain the fail signature.  So, how do I figure out where in the source code this is occurring?  How do I go the next step and get where the assignment was at that caused the issue?  Again, this is a large body of source code and it appears there are many static assignments of strings.  I need to narrow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the top section of the trace didn't help (this is normally the only section I have to look at):

```
03-23     23:37:14.313: I/DEBUG(28):          #00  pc 0000e7c8  /system/lib/libc.so
03-23     23:37:14.313: I/DEBUG(28):          #01  pc 00063cd4  /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/libgnustl_shared.so
```

but further down I see lines line this:

```
03-23 23:37:14.344: I/DEBUG(28):     bea814d4  8131f228  /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/libsharedB.so
```

If I use addr2line on this and the other lines showing that recently a function in libsharedB.so was on the stack, I get my answer.  The only additional trick was 8131f228 wasn't the address I needed to enter.  Instead, I needed to enter, 0131f228.  The 80000000 is the base address of the library, the rest is the address within that space.

Comment: Glad you got to the bottom of this, it was properly confusing! What was the nature of the fault in libsharedB?